# Top 5 Results per Subject

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ranking

I have a list of exam subjects, student numbers and the score of each student per subject. What I'm trying to do is identify the top 4 scoring students per subject.

An example of the data that I have currently:

```
+--------------------+-------------+------------+
|      Subject       | Student ID  | Test Score |
+--------------------+-------------+------------+
| Maths 1            | Student 001 |         78 |
| Maths 2            | Student 001 |         63 |
| English Lang       | Student 001 |         64 |
| English Lit        | Student 001 |         88 |
| Chemistry          | Student 001 |         89 |
| Biology            | Student 001 |         81 |
| Physics            | Student 001 |         42 |
| French             | Student 001 |         73 |
| Spanish            | Student 001 |         78 |
| German             | Student 001 |         67 |
| Engineering        | Student 001 |         38 |
| Design & Tech      | Student 001 |         57 |
| ...                |   ...       |        ... |
| ICT                | Student 002 |         95 |
| Physical Education | Student 002 |         73 |
| Law                | Student 002 |         37 |
| Sociology          | Student 002 |         66 |
| Art & Design       | Student 002 |         40 |
| Drama              | Student 002 |         51 |
| Dance              | Student 002 |         75 |
| General Studies    | Student 002 |         37 |
| Maths 1            | Student 003 |         56 |
| Maths 2            | Student 003 |         77 |
| English Lang       | Student 003 |         41 |
| ...                |   ...       |        ... |
| Sociology          | Student 003 |         48 |
| Art & Design       | Student 003 |         79 |
| Drama              | Student 003 |         61 |
| Dance              | Student 003 |         96 |
| General Studies    | Student 003 |         50 |
| Maths 1            | Student 004 |         45 |
| Maths 2            | Student 004 |         73 |
| English Lang       | Student 004 |         40 |
| English Lit        | Student 004 |         60 |
| Chemistry          | Student 004 |         77 |
| Biology            | Student 004 |         56 |
| Physics            | Student 004 |         69 |
| French             | Student 004 |         90 |
| ...                |   ...       |        ... |
+--------------------+-------------+------------+
```

So Far I've created a pivot table with the subject as the Row Label, Student ID as the Column Label and the Sum of Test Scores as the Values, which gives me something like this:

```
+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+-------------+
|     Row Labels     | Student 001 | Student 002 | ... | Student 097 | Student 098 |
+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+-------------+
| Art & Design       |          88 |          85 | ... |          79 |          91 |
| Biology            |          81 |         123 | ... |          70 |          56 |
| Business Studies   |          64 |         124 | ... |          47 |          51 |
| Chemistry          |          89 |         100 | ... |          41 |          77 |
| Dance              |          67 |         170 | ... |          96 |          36 |
| Design & Tech      |          57 |         131 | ... |          31 |          89 |
| Drama              |          35 |         130 | ... |          61 |          61 |
| Engineering        |          38 |         125 | ... |          38 |          58 |
| English Lang       |          64 |         102 | ... |          41 |          40 |
| English Lit        |          88 |         160 | ... |          81 |          60 |
| French             |          73 |          92 | ... |          69 |          90 |
| General Studies    |          37 |         125 | ... |          50 |          63 |
| Geography          |          41 |         117 | ... |          89 |          93 |
| German             |          67 |          77 | ... |          33 |          89 |
| History            |          85 |         176 | ... |          82 |          79 |
| Home Economics     |          89 |         155 | ... |          71 |          46 |
| ICT                |          85 |         179 | ... |          82 |          63 |
| Law                |          46 |         102 | ... |          72 |          68 |
| Maths 1            |          78 |          98 | ... |          56 |          45 |
| Maths 2            |          63 |         137 | ... |          77 |          73 |
| Physical Education |          82 |         138 | ... |          30 |          80 |
| Physics            |          42 |         108 | ... |          40 |          69 |
| Religious Studies  |          66 |         113 | ... |          95 |          73 |
| Sociology          |          87 |         152 | ... |          48 |          59 |
| Spanish            |          78 |         152 | ... |          70 |          50 |
+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+-------------+
```

I've then used the **large** function adjacent to the table to give me the top 5 scores per row. However, what I need is the top 5 students ID's with the corresponding scores, rather than just the scores.

Apologies for the long post, I hope this all makes sense?

UPDATE -

Ideally I need an output similar to the following:

```
+--------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|                    |  Result 1  |  Result 2  |  Result 3  |  Result 4  |  Result 5  |
+--------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Art & Design       | Student 92 | Student 88 | Student 85 | Student 62 | Student 94 |
| Biology            | Student 86 | Student 74 | Student 63 | Student 90 | Student 60 |
| Business Studies   | Student 56 | Student 66 | Student 77 | Student 97 | Student 97 |
| Chemistry          | Student 86 | Student 67 | Student 95 | Student 58 | Student 56 |
| Dance              | Student 91 | Student 65 | Student 76 | Student 82 | Student 87 |
| Design & Tech      | Student 57 | Student 60 | Student 91 | Student 85 | Student 92 |
| Drama              | Student 52 | Student 91 | Student 67 | Student 80 | Student 81 |
| Engineering        | Student 58 | Student 82 | Student 95 | Student 88 | Student 71 |
| English Lang       | Student 87 | Student 69 | Student 53 | Student 63 | Student 71 |
| English Lit        | Student 93 | Student 75 | Student 78 | Student 91 | Student 77 |
| French             | Student 76 | Student 64 | Student 92 | Student 63 | Student 80 |
| General Studies    | Student 53 | Student 95 | Student 97 | Student 51 | Student 82 |
| Geography          | Student 70 | Student 77 | Student 54 | Student 75 | Student 64 |
| German             | Student 90 | Student 50 | Student 60 | Student 73 | Student 92 |
| History            | Student 75 | Student 61 | Student 78 | Student 64 | Student 92 |
| Home Economics     | Student 89 | Student 75 | Student 92 | Student 60 | Student 70 |
| ICT                | Student 51 | Student 53 | Student 54 | Student 87 | Student 97 |
| Law                | Student 92 | Student 86 | Student 67 | Student 55 | Student 50 |
| Maths 1            | Student 64 | Student 88 | Student 50 | Student 71 | Student 91 |
| Maths 2            | Student 71 | Student 82 | Student 93 | Student 64 | Student 64 |
| Physical Education | Student 80 | Student 70 | Student 89 | Student 82 | Student 64 |
| Physics            | Student 93 | Student 78 | Student 94 | Student 55 | Student 53 |
| Religious Studies  | Student 92 | Student 80 | Student 70 | Student 57 | Student 63 |
| Sociology          | Student 58 | Student 51 | Student 91 | Student 68 | Student 71 |
| Spanish            | Student 88 | Student 93 | Student 79 | Student 71 | Student 76 |
+--------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table is a good option.

Put subject and student id (in that order) into the Row Labels field. Place Test Score into Values field.

You need to right click on any of the values in the second column > sort > largest to smallest

[image]

Comment: This works for the data when I'm trying to find the top 4 values in the case where there are only 4 students, but in my scenario I've got 98.  - see edit of OP.

Answer (score 0):

After your create the above pivot,

paste special only the values to a new blank excel sheet.

Now transpose it into a new or same sheet... (shortcut  is alt  e + s+ e) ( so now subjects would be columns and student no.s as rows)

Now sort on subject from large to small (you will have sort manually as many number of times as the number of subjects

Alternate:
Ignore the above Pivot you made
Create a new pivot table with student no. in rows, subjects in columns and sort on subjects from large to small